# Quoted Printables Encoding - counting Bits

Tags: quoted-printable

Let's say I want to encode a word in quoted printable (with charset ISO 8859-1) and count bits afterwards. How do you count the encoded quoted printable tag ("=" and hex) in bits?

- Original: hätte -> 7+8+7+7+7 = 36 Bits
- Encoded: h=E4tte -> does "=E4" count for 3*7 Bits or 1*7 Bits?

Comment: What's the rule to determine that a character counts as 7 bits?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález ISO 8859-1?

Comment: ISO-8859-1 is both a fixed-width encoding and an 8-bit encoding. There're variable-width encodings, such as UTF-8, but they're normally multiple of 8 bits anyway. Whatever, I'm probably misunderstanding something really basic in your question—I'm sorry.

Comment: Original: hätte -> 8+8+8+8+8 = 40 bits; 
Encoded: how much bits has the string "=E4"? 8 Bits or 24 Bits?